# Why was "from" used in this sentence ("one must command from each what each can perform...")?

Tags: prepositions

This is from the Little Prince, and the king says as below:

> ﻿"One must command **from** each what each can perform," the king went on. "Authority is based first of all upon reason. If you command your subjects to jump into the ocean, there will be a revolution. I am entitled to command obedience because my orders are reasonable."﻿

I don't understand why "from" is used here, since command is a transitive verb thus used without prepositions such as in "He commanded his men to retreat".

What's the use of "from" here?

If the sentence has no problem, than is "He commanded **from** his men to retreat" also acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Command** is used here in the sense of **require**.

It's an oratorical way of saying **command each person to give what they are capable of**.

**Command** can be used both transitively (with a direct object) and intransitively (without one). Here it is being used intransitively.

But you can't say: **commanded from his men to....**.

You need to say: **He commanded his men to retreat**. Here, **command** is being used as a transitive verb and **his men** is the object.

So it depends on how the sentence is constructed.

For more on **command**, see: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/command_2